# Что необходимо для запуска Java-программ?

Tags: java

Предположим я написал программу. Самую простую, калькулятор какой-нибудь. Он весит, грубо говоря, 20 мб., бинарники + исходники + пр. ресурсы. Чтобы запустить программу нужна явамашина. Она есть в JDK.

Чтобы другие люди смогли оценить мой "супер-калькулятор" им нужно всем скачивать и устанавливать JDK? Ведь JDK весит намного больше чем моя программа.

Comment: Нет, им достаточно установить JRE.

Comment: Ну и надо очень постараться, чтобы простой калькулятор вешал 20 Mb.

Comment: Я сейчас из любопытства глянул — jar-файл Minecraft 1.12.2 весит 10 мегабайт. Очень интересный у вас калькулятор получился :)

Comment: начиная с java 9 для создания автономного дистрибутива можно воспользоваться утилитой [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm), которая скопирует jvm и нужные зависимости из поставки jre. Steve Perkins в своем блоге [пишет](https://steveperkins.com/using-java-9-modularization-to-ship-zero-dependency-native-apps/), что консольный Hello World займет 22 МБ, а оконный на JavaFX - 46 МБ.

Comment: Я целых 2 предложения потратил на описание того, что калькулятор "гипотетический". Мне с вами явно не соревноваться в остроумии на тему размера проектов, так почему бы по делу не поговорить?

Comment: @LogIN вам ещё в первом комментарии ответили, что пользователю нужно будет [JRE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Runtime_Environment). О чём тут ещё говорить? Если хотите избавить пользователя от обязанности по скачиванию и установке JRE, можете использовать входящую в JDK утилиту [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javapackager.html) для создания дистрибутива, включающего JRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще есть вариант поставлять все вместе, т.е. ваш Jar и JRE(он портабельный). Просто создайте директорию с Вашим Jar и рядом с JRE примерно так

```
MyApp
  ├ myJar.jar
  ├jre [jre directory]
  └ start.sh (или start.bat)
```

и можно еще написать скрипт запуска start вида `./jre/bin/java -jar ./myJar.jar`.
Кроме того существуют конвертеры которые преобразуют Jar в нативный код (довольно много Jar to exe конвертеров)

Answer (score 3):

НЕТ, JDK - набор разработчик (JRE + для разработки),
для запуска jar архивов(запускаемых джава-архивов) нужно только JRE.
ХОтя и JRE весит гораздо больше чем твой калькулятор

Например на с++ тебе не нужно что либо скачивать помимо самой запускаемой программы, но тебе нужно будет компилировать свой код под огромное множество различных процессоров. Т.Е ты не сможешь просто написать программу , скинуть exe файл на другой компьютер и запустить её(Вернее сможешь, но он не всегда будет запускаться).